# How to convert string of characters to their respective int values?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to convert a `string` of characters into their ASCII `int` values. However I cannot get this to work for one even one character in the `string`. I would expect a result of 72 when entering 'H', but it returns a 0 (the same for every character I've tried).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;

    cin >> a;

    const char * b = a.c_str();

    int c = atoi(b);

    cout << int(c) << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A char already holds the ascii value. Just assign the char to an int. You use atoi when you want to convert "7" to 7.

Comment: what do you mean by their respective int value? if string is "abc", do you expect to have 97+98+99? or simply just have another array of int type, like int arr[3] = {97, 98, 99}?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert each character in string to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577182/convert-each-character-in-string-to-ascii)

Comment: One really pedantic edge case: it is still possible to get IBM’s mainframe compiler to use EBCDIC instead of ASCII as its character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atoi` parses the C-string interpreting its content as an integral number, i.e.

```
int i = atoi("123"); // i = 123
```

You don't want this: you want to know the ASCII value of every single character of the input string. To figure this out, you can use this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    for(int c: a) 
        cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite used to the `string` library but simply type:

```
cout<<(int)a[pozition];
```

You can place that in a for like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    cout<<(int)a[i]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast each character to an int

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        cout << (int) a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```